# Get the machine logged in username using python

Tags: python-3.x, angularjs, flask

I have my web application developed on Angular JS and python. Angular JS is deployed in windows machine and service code in Linux. This has the REST urls developed using flask. The ask is for enabling the users not to enter the user ID and get it from windows machine logged in user. We cannot move to cloud as of now. We have to get the machine logged in user from GUI(deployed in windows) to the python code(Linux server) on 1st request(GET). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can use NTLM but you'll need to setup Apache to serve Flask and integrate it with your network domain controller. Then, in Flask, just query `request.environ.get('AUTH_USER', '')`.

Comment: Cant we do it with ngnix?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. NGINX is way simpler then Apache (which almost works as a application server).